# Extract one unique SBox from Canonical Representative

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, s-boxes

In paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/218.pdf, the author has examined 16! different 4 bit SBoxes and at the end of investigation, introduced an  optimal class which named "Golden SBoxes". How can I extract one SBoxes from this class?

I mean by knowing the canonical representation of Golden SBoxes as "035869C7DAE41FB2","03586CB79EADF214","03586AF4ED9217CB" and "03586CB7A49EF12D"(table 4 of paper),

how can I extract the golden sboxes such as Serpent S-Box S3, Hummingbird-1  SBoxes S1, S2, and S3 and Hummingbird-2 SBoxes S0 and S1?

Answer (score 2):

This illustrates the idea with no efficiencies considered. Take the canonical Sbox, and let $$X:=[X[1],\ldots,X[16]]$$
be the vectors in $\{0,1\}^4$ in the order given by the canonical Sbox map.

Looping through all invertible $4\times4$ matrices $M_0,M_i$ and all constant vectors $c_0,c_i$ compute the list of column matrices
$$
F(M_0,M_i,c_0,c_i):=M_0 \cdot [M_i\cdot(X[1]\oplus c_i),M_i\cdot(X[2]\oplus c_i), \ldots M_i\cdot(X[16]\oplus c_i)]\oplus [c_0,\ldots,c_0],
$$
and you will find the target Sboxes for some $F$ computed during this process.

See extract from the paper *quoted in the question* below:

[image: here]

Comment: paper link is not available.I can not extract paper from the given link.

Comment: its the paper from the question

Answer (score 2):

in extension to koldu answer , $M_0$ and $M_1$ are 4 bit binary matrices, the number of invertible binary matrices is 20160 (approximately $2^{14}$) using this formula:

$$\sharp S_n=\prod_{k=1}^n(2^n-2^{k-1})$$ where $n$ is 4 bit in this case.

there are two binary matrices and two affine constants (size of $2^4$) , the computation complexity is quite high using brute force , therefore , there are some tricks such as [An Improved Affine Equivalence Algorithm for Random Permutations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/115.pdf) to reduce complexity.